# How to get started?

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

I am trying to get started with HP Nonstop and am trying to set up a local development environment

http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/nl/en/enterprise/servers/integrity/nonstop/nonstop-development.aspx#.W8SYvxNKhQJ

There are some dead links here. Does anyone know how to get started with it if I don't have access to a Tandem server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the latest (?) trial version of the native mode developer environment:
https://h20392.www2.hpe.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=QSB98V1

You will need a NonStop server to actually execute any compiled code on.